# Draw rectangle in the selection, Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw rectangle or square in selection area to show the selected xAxis min, max and yAxis min max in highchart.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what have you tried? What problems you faced? Please share a jsFiddle of your attempt so we can improve on it to help you

Comment: This is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/meFgf/

Comment: Thanks Igor here is the updated link that i exactly asked http://jsfiddle.net/meFgf/1/

Comment: (100,100,100,100,0) set up the coordinates liuke this to actually see a 100x100 square in position (100,100) the last parameter seems to be  like a border-radius

Answer (score 0):

Explaining @igor-shastin's [example](http://jsfiddle.net/meFgf/)...

- Set [zoomType](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType) to `"xy"`
- Add a [rect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) to the chart with 0 dimensions and hang onto the reference
- In the [selection](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection) event:

  - Grab the `event.xAxis[0].min` and `.max`; same for `.yAxis`
  - Update the [rect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) coordinates so it renders where the selection was made
  - Return `false` and/or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent actually zooming